# Difficulty with passing the value of a tl to the tikzfading function

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3, tikz-fadings

In the LaTeX tikz library "fadings", there is a function called \tikzfading that allows one to define a custom fading style. For instance, the following is an MWE showing a line fading out from (0,0) towards the 8 compass directions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\tikzfading[name=myfade, outer color=transparent!100, inner color=transparent!0]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \foreach \theta in {0,...,7} {
        \coordinate (B) at ({cos(45*\theta)},{sin(45*\theta)});
        \draw[path fading=myfade, fit fading=false] (A) -- (B);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is what the code compiles to:

[image]

---

Now for my question, I am running into trouble when combining a construction like the above with expl3. Suppose that I wanted to define a function that drew the above diagram, but also allowed the user to pass optional additional options to the tikz fading style. My idea on how do to this was to create a function called \set_fade:n that creates the tikz fading style by storing in a sequence the options specified by the user along with the inner and outer options as above, and then creating a tl variable whose value is the expanded sequence, and then using that tl in the definition of the fading style. We can then create a document command with an optional argument that begins by calling \set_fade:n with an empty {} argument if the user does not specify any options, or calling \set_fade:n {#1} if they do. Then function \foo can proceed with the original MWE. If we do this, we get something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \set_fade:n #1 {
    \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
    \seq_put_left:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {inner~color=transparent!0}
    \seq_put_left:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {outer~color=transparent!100}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {,}}
    \tikzfading[name=myfade, \l_tmpa_tl]
}

\NewDocumentCommand\foo{o}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\set_fade:n {}}{\set_fade:n {#1}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \foreach \theta in {0,...,7} {
            \coordinate (B) at ({cos(45*\theta)},{sin(45*\theta)});
            \draw[path~fading=myfade, fit~fading=false] (A) -- (B);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foo

\end{document}
```

However, this code does not compile properly. The primary error thrown is

```
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `outer color=transparent'.
```

After some reading, I have gathered that the error is down to the way that expl3 is interpreting the ! character in the value of the tl \l_tmpa_tl. If I use \tl_show:N on \l_tmpa_tl, I get the correct string of characters: "outer color=transparent!100,inner color=transparent!0", but it seems that when I input the tl into \tikzfading, the expansion of \l_tmpa_tl stops at the exclamation mark, causing the resulting sequence \tikzfading[name=myfade,outer~color=transparent], which explains the error.

I imagine that I need to do some sort of character class control on the exclamation mark, but I cannot seem to find the correct way to do this. So my questions are:

1. Is this roughly the right idea of how to handle this sort of thing?
2. If not, how else should I try to do so?
3. If it is, how do I correctly handle this exclamation mark character?

---

I have found one potential solution. If I change the definition of \set_fade:n to

```
\cs_new:Npn \set_fade:n #1 {
    \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
    \seq_put_left:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {inner~color=transparent! 0}
    \seq_put_left:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {outer~color=transparent! 100}
    \seq_put_left:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {name=myfade}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {,}}
    \exp_args:NNV \tikzfading[ \l_tmpa_tl ]
}
```

then the whole thing now works. Can anyone explain to me why? And is this an optimal solution?

Comment: Expansion issue. `\l_tmpa_tl` needs to be expanded at least once. A PGF/TikZ solution would be `style/.expand~once=\l_tmpa_tl`. Otherwise the PGFKeys parser sees the whole `\l_tmpa_tl` as one key (without a value). And since the whole construct is not a known key it sees a `!` and assumes it to be a color specification.

Comment: Your proposed solution seems good enough. Depending on what `#1` contains you might run into trouble if it contains a `[`/ `]` but that's another issue. But with your MWE it's hard to understand why you're using clists at all.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the cause of the bug with the original code, and also suggesting a solution.

Comment: If your code is not just a simplified version, but what you're really using, your `seq`-approach is completely unnecessary, instead simply use `\cs_new:Npn \set_fade:n #1 { \tikzfading [{name = myfade, outer~color = transparent ! 100, inner~color = transparent! 0, #1}] }`. Also instead of using an `o`-argument and then doing `\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\foo{}}{\foo{#1}}` you could simply use an `O{}`-argument and then `\foo{#1}`.

Comment: Thank you for helping to simplify the code significantly!